# Fullcalendar May and June both showing value 4

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

We have an issue with fullcalendar http://fullcalendar.io/. If we click on next, both May and June is showing 4th month. Click on next or previous button in header.

Are we missing something?

Code line: 
**alert('viewRender view month: ' + view.start._d.getMonth());**

Fiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/sudiptabanerjee/z7La379f/2/

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // defaultDate: '2016-06-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            viewRender: function (view, element) {

               alert('viewRender view month: ' + view.start._d.getMonth());
            },
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2016-06-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2016-06-07',
                    end: '2016-06-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2016-06-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2016-06-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2016-06-11',
                    end: '2016-06-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2016-06-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2016-06-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2016-06-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2016-06-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2016-06-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2016-06-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2016-06-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2016-06-28'
                }
            ]
        });

    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        background-color:#fff;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in JS, month start from 0,

```
0 - Jan
1 - Feb
2 - Mar
3 - Apr
4 - May
5 - June
```

When u navigate to May in month view the first day of the month is **1** (ie, **May 1**)
and for **June** the first day of the month is **29** (ie, **May 29**), both are May

**the number for May is 4**

it is showing the correct month,

EDIT
[https://jsfiddle.net/z7La379f/3/](http://Plunker%20edited)

if you are looking to get the month of the current view you can do this

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {

// alert('viewRender element: '+element.start._d.getMonth());
//  alert('viewRender view month: ' + view.start._d.getMonth());
var dt=moment(view.start).add(10,'days');
var mnth =moment(dt).month();
alert(mnth);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

FullCalendar's [documentatation for `view`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View_Object/) says `start` is:

> A Moment that is the first visible day.
>
> **In month-view, this value is often before the 1st day of the month**, because most months do not begin on the first day-of-week.

*(My emphasis.)*

When you go to June, look at the day in the upper left-hand corner and observe what month it's in.

---

Side note: Don't use the undocumented internals of libraries. Instead of `view.start._d.getMonth()` use `view.start.month()` or `view.start.toDate().getMonth()`.